# Ошибка компилятора CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите решить проблему кто знает как. Ошибка `CS0619`, незнаю что делать.

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(10,16): error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите ошибку и условия её возникновения в текстовом виде в вопросе

Comment: Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(10,16): error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'

Comment: попробуй использовать вместо GUI.Text UI.Text

Comment: Как это сделать ?

Comment: Добавьте фрагмент неработающей части кода в вопрос текстом, и вам подскажут, как поправить

Answer (score 3):

Написано же что устарела `GUITexture` и `GUITex` используйте `UI.Image` и `UI.Image.Text`

Answer (score 1):

Сначала подключи **UnityEngine.UI** и замени где **GUIText** на **Text**